# Graphviz crossing edges

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to avoid the crossing of the lines between 20->40 and 30->70. Does anyone know how to do this? I am using single points to straighten out the edges but I would have expected the rendering engine to avoid these edges to overlap. Here is my dot code:

```
digraph {
graph [splines="ortho", nodesep = "1", overlap = false];
node [shape=rectangle, color=lightgrey, style=filled ];

10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90


node[shape=none, width=0, height=0 label=""];
edge[dir=none];

{rank=same;
p1->10
10->p2
}

p1->20
p2->30


{rank=same;
p3->40
40->p4
}

p3->50
p4->60


{rank=same;
p5->70
70->p6
}

p5->80
p6->90


20->40
30->70
}
```

I wanted to post an image, but stackoverflow does not allow me to do this... You can see what I mean when you copy the code into: http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/

I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: +1 for the link to GraphvizFiddle - didn't know about this tool, great stuff!

Answer (score 2):

You could give graphviz a hint by adding an invisible edge between p4 an dp5:

```
{
    rank=same;
    p3 -> 40;
    40 -> p4;
    p4 -> p5 [style=invis]; // new invisible edge
    p5 -> 70;
    70 -> p6;
}
```

---

If you are not able to add invisible edges (dynamic graph generation), make sure nodes which are part of a subgraph do appear first within the subgraph, and therefore avoid upfront node definitions.

In this example, I removed the node definitions in the beginning of the script and inlined the style of the elbow-joint nodes.

[Here's the GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1411590304091#digraph%20%7B%0Agraph%20[splines%3D%22ortho%22%2C%20nodesep%20%3D%20%221%22%2C%20overlap%20%3D%20false]%3B%0Anode%20[shape%3Drectangle%2C%20color%3Dlightgrey%2C%20style%3Dfilled%20]%3B%0A%0A%2F%2Fnode[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0Aedge[dir%3Dnone]%3B%0A%0A%7B%0A%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20p1[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p2[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p1-%3E10%0A%2010-%3Ep2%0A%7D%0A%0Ap1-%3E20%0Ap2-%3E30%0A%0A%7B%0A%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20p3[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p4[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p3-%3E40%0A%2040-%3Ep4%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Ap3-%3E50%0Ap4-%3E60%0A%0A%7B%0A%20rank%3Dsame%3B%0A%20p5[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p6[shape%3Dnone%2C%20width%3D0%2C%20height%3D0%2C%20label%3D%22%22]%3B%0A%20p5-%3E70%0A%2070-%3Ep6%0A%7D%0A%0Ap5-%3E80%0Ap6-%3E90%0A%0A%0A20-%3E40%0A30-%3E70%0A%0A%7D)

```
digraph {
graph [splines="ortho", nodesep = "1", overlap = false];
node [shape=rectangle, color=lightgrey, style=filled ];

//node[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
edge[dir=none];

{
 rank=same;
 p1[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p2[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p1->10
 10->p2
}

p1->20
p2->30

{
 rank=same;
 p3[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p4[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p3->40
 40->p4
}


p3->50
p4->60

{
 rank=same;
 p5[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p6[shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
 p5->70
 70->p6
}

p5->80
p6->90


20->40
30->70

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for this static example! How could I make this work in a dynamic mode? I don't know in advance at what "level" the nodes will be displayed so dynamically adding hidden edges seems difficult... really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: I'm with you about the invisible edges! I added a more generic solution, hope it'll work with your real-world cases.

Comment: Getting closer! So not providing the node definitions make this work... Unfortunately I do need the nodes defined because the height and width of the nodes are calculated based on label size...

Comment: In the above example, the nodes do have the exact same attributes (height, width, label) as before, the only difference is that they are not listed first. If you have some precalculated width/height (external to graphviz), you could still declare the node first with its attributes, just do it within the subgraph it appears first (like the p1, p2 ,... nodes).

Comment: Great, I figured this out after your previous comment. Thanks again for all you help.